# How kubectl port-forward works?

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, kubectl

`kubectl` exposes commands that can be used to create a Service for an application and assigns an IP address to access it from internet.

As far as I understand, to access any application within Kubernetes cluster there should be a Service resource created and that should have an IP address which is accessible from an external network.

But in case of `port-forward` how does `kubectl` create a connection to the application without an IP address which is accessible externally?

Comment: Did you read up on https://prefetch.net/blog/2018/02/03/how-the-kubectl-port-forward-command-works/ already?

Comment: It's a call via the API server.  It's not a general way to avoid needing a Service.  It's neither fast nor, in my experience, especially reliable, but it's useful for debugging.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas no, just saw it... now got new qn, how socat port-forwarder does port forwarding?

Comment: @DavidMaze possible for you to elaborate?

Comment: @karthikeayan found another useful link https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/accessing-services-from-the-outside/#api-access the actual traffic is going through API server endpoint Ex - https://api.CLUSTER_ID.k8s.gigantic.io/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/NAMESPACE/services/SERVICE_NAME:PORT_NAME/proxy/

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`kubectl port-forward` makes a specific [Kubernetes API request](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#-strong-proxy-operations-pod-v1-core-strong-).  That means the system running it needs access to the API server, and any traffic will get tunneled over a single HTTP connection.

Having this is really useful for debugging (if one specific pod is acting up you can connect to it directly; in a microservice environment you can talk to a back-end service you wouldn't otherwise expose) but it's not an alternative to setting up service objects.  When I've worked with `kubectl port-forward` it's been visibly slower than connecting to a pod via a service, and I've found seen the command just stop after a couple of minutes.  Again these aren't big problems for debugging, but they're not what I'd want for a production system.

Comment: I agree but i think that is also very useful in production for security: with a simple run script, you can use port forwarding to access admin tools and sensible data that you don't want to expose to outside of the cluster

Comment: Is it meant to be used in a production environment?

Comment: Agreed that it's not meant for production / services, but about the duration the docs say: "The forwarding session ends when the selected pod terminates, and rerun of the command is needed to resume forwarding." https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward

Answer (score 233):

To start, it's useful to note and remember that in Kubernetes, *every* pod gets its own ip address from 10.*, that is usable only within the cluster. Now, the `port-forward` feature of kubectl simply tunnels the traffic from a specified port at your local host machine to the specified port on the specified pod. API server then becomes, in a sense, a temporary gateway between your local port and the Kubernetes cluster.

`kubectl port-forward` forwards connections to a local port to a port on a pod. Compared to `kubectl proxy`, `kubectl port-forward` is more generic as it can forward TCP traffic while `kubectl proxy` can only forward HTTP traffic.

`kubectl port-forward` is useful for testing/debugging purposes so you can access your service locally without exposing it.

Below is the name of the `pod` and it will forward it's port `6379` to `localhost:6379`.

```
kubectl port-forward redis-master-765d459796-258hz 6379:6379
```

which is the same as

```
kubectl port-forward pods/redis-master-765d459796-258hz 6379:6379
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/redis-master 6379:6379
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward rs/redis-master 6379:6379
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward svc/redis-master 6379:6379
```

Comment: I still not getting as because TCP traffic also travel using IP itself.

Comment: Link to sample is broken

Comment: If you are interested in bulk port-forwarding an entire namespace or a set of services based on selectors to your local workstation you can try kubefwd https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd

Comment: @cjimti finally i can get rid of nodeports.. this will be super useful!

Comment: @Ivthillo using the same port number is a bad idea because it creates confusion. I don't understand which is pods port and which is the local one when writing the command.

Comment: @Daniel I understand it can be confusing (just like port mapping with docker) but when you know the syntax there is nothing wrong with forwarding ports on the same port number

Comment: ```Unable to listen on port 443: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:443: bind: permission denied unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:443: bind: permission denied]
``` Im getting this error when i use port-forward

Comment: But it sometimes result in error when too much traffic generated from local host.  I have observed below three errors. `j.n.UnknownHostException: docker.for.mac.host.internal`
`i.n.c.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: docker.for.mac.host.internal/192.168.65.2:8888`
`i.g.h.c.i.RequestTimeoutException: Request timeout to docker.for.mac.host.internal/192.168.65.2:8888 after 60000 ms`

Comment: `kubectl port-forward svc/redis-master 6379:6379` - this version is actually slightly different from others as in this case port 6379 should be exposed through service. So, it can't forward traffic to a random port of the pod. An error will occur if port is not exposed: "error: Service redis-master does not have a service port 6379".

Comment: you forgot to mention that the namespace is necessary too!

Answer (score 66):

If you want to forward to a different port in localhost. Try this

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <localhost-port>:<pod-port>
```

```
kubectl port-forward sample-pod-sadasds-sxawdd 8090:6379
```

The above command forwards to localhost 8090 from pod 6379

Answer (score 42):

The port-forward command, Forwards one (or more) local ports to a pod.

This command is very useful for example in blue/green deployments where you would want to troubleshoot a misbehaving pod.

To take things even further, you could even execute some preliminary tests to the pods you feel could be more error-prone right inside your CI/CD pipeline in Jenkins by using multiple conditions, declarative pipeline.

Usage examples:

**Listen on port 8888 locally, forwarding to 5000 in the pod**

```
kubectl port-forward pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

**Listen on port 8888 on all addresses, forwarding to 5000 in the pod**

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

**Listen on a random port locally, forwarding to 5000 in the pod**

```
kubectl port-forward pod/mypod :5000
```

**Listen on port 8888 on localhost and selected IP, forwarding to 5000 in the pod**

```
kubectl port-forward --address localhost,10.19.21.23 pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

**Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in the pod**

```
kubectl port-forward pod/mypod 5000 6000
```

**Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in a pod selected by the deployment**

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/mydeployment 5000 6000
```

**Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in a pod selected by the service**

```
kubectl port-forward service/myservice 5000 6000
```

Comment: An important detailed only stressed in this answer is "in a pod selected by the service". Thus you never port-forward to a service LB. Restarting the (randomly selected) pod of this service will break the connection as steted here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward

Comment: I can not say the nasty words I've been thinking when port-forwarding works outside... Nice Answer!

Answer (score 9):

`kubectl port-forward` is the easiest communication method with the Pod, but under the hood, this method is much more complicated. The communication goes through several Kubernetes components, so if anything is broken in the communication path, you will not be able to talk to the pod, even if the pod itself is accessible via regular communication channels.

The server proxy runs via `kubectl port-forward` command forwards the connection to the [Kubernetes API Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) living in **Master node**, then the [API Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) delivers the connection to [the Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) on the node hosting your Pod, and then [the Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) forwards the connection to the application running in the pod's container.

**NOTE**

> The application in the container must be bound to a port on the
> loopback device for the Kubelet to reach it. If it listens only on the
> pod’s eth0 network interface, you won’t be able to reach it with the
> kubectl port-forward command.

[Marko Lukša "Kubernetes in Action, Second Edition"](https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action-second-edition)

**TIP**

`kubectl port-forward` allows you to forward communication also to Services and has several other useful features. Run `kubectl port-forward --help` to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

To access something inside the cluster, there ae a couple of different options available to,

1. Cluster IP service with Ingress-Nginx
2. NodePort Service to expose the pod directly to the outside world.

Above both approach will require to write config file, In case if you want to access a pod without writing a config file then it comes to third option.

3. **Port Forward:** We can run a command at our terminal that tells our kubernets cluster to port-forward a port off a very specific pod inside of our cluster when we use this port forwarding thing that's going to cause our cluster to essentially behaves as though it has a node port service running inside it. It's going to expose this pod or a very specific port on it to the outside world and allow us to connect to it directly from our local machine.

Let's go by an example:

```
const stan = nats.connect('ticketing', 'abc', {
  url: 'http://localhost:5000',
});
```

Our goal is to establish a connection between stan and a pod inside a kubernets cluster.

first we will need the pod name, you can get the name by command **kubectl get pods**

```
kubectl get pods
```

I am assuming my pod name is **nats-depl-855d477f4d-xgbd7**, and it is accessiable via a cluster IP service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nats-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: nats
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4222
      targetPort: 4222
```

now to establish the connection run the below command:

```
kubectl port-forward nats-depl-855d477f4d-xgbd7 5000:4222
```

5000: is the port of my local machine

4222 : is the port of the pod I want to get access