# How does port-forward avoid mtls

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, istio

I have istio set up with mtls globally enabled. I have verifed it by bashing into a pot without an envoy sidecar, and running a curl command on http, which failed. Then run a curl on HTTPS using the Istio certs, which worked.

When I port-forward to a service, eq `kubectl port-forward svc/my-svc 8080:80` I am able to access my app by going to `http://localhost:8080`
I would expect that this wouldn't work, since mtls is being enforced. 
How does this port-forward with kubernetes work? Does it go directly to the node, thereby by-passing the sidecar?

Comment: Port forwarding goes to the process of the pause container using nsenter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How kubectl port-forward works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468491/how-kubectl-port-forward-works)

Comment: HI @Akar, I read the answers there before asking, but it doesn't answer this case. I.E. forwarding to a pod isn't specific enough, since in the case of istio, it sits in the pod and should be intercepting all traffic.

Comment: Could you please share the configuration of pod deployment and my-svc service?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that **Istio** is working in parallel with standard Kubernetes network services and does not affect traffic in case of `port-forwarding`.

**Istio** network service will create iptables rule exactly the same as `kubectl port-forward` or any other standard command do.

Unfortunately, I did not find any official documentation with an explanation of how it works.