# how to do port forwarding in kubernetes like docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  container-name:
    image: container-image
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

And it creates the container with port forwarding to host machine.
docker inspect container-name

```
[...]
NetworkSettings: {
  [...]
  Ports: {
    443/tcp: [{ HostIp: 0.0.0.0, HostPort: 443 }]
    80/tcp: [{ HostIp: 0.0.0.0, HostPort: 80 }]
  }
  [...]
}
[...]
```

But in the kubernetes next pod.yml, create container without ports.

```
kind: Pod
matadata:
  name: pod-name
spec:
  containers:
  - image: container-image
    name: container-name
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
    [...]
```

In short, I need forward container(pod) port to host machine(node).

I found out that better to expose. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Pods/containers are "moving" things in Kubernetes (they might be rescheduled to a different machine). Publishing ports to the host is not the solution here. What you are looking for is a Kubernetes abstraction called [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Comment: Check the available *service types* [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). You probably need "ClusterIP" or "NodePort".

Answer (score 7):

The kubernetes way" to prefer would be to expose your pod through a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) and control it with a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

If you want for some reason use the port-forwarding this is how you do:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/pod-name 8080:80 8443:443 -n default
```

This is going to bind on your host ports `8080` and `8443`, forwarding the traffic to the ports `80` and `443` respectively for the pod with the name `pod-name`. I have not omitted the namespace (`default`), by default `kubectl` will use your [current-context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts)

Comment: It should be noted though that `kubectl port-forward ...` is for debugging purposes and stops working after a timeout is reached. More at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476393/1561148) by [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze).

Comment: I don't think there is a timeout, about the duration the docs say: "The forwarding session ends when the selected pod terminates, and rerun of the command is needed to resume forwarding." https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward

Answer (score 0):

if you know the port your application is using maybe you can use:

kubectl port-forward  LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_PORT

Something like:
kubectl port-forward  8080:80

This assumes that your pod is in default namespace. If you deployed in another namespace you can pass use the -n  parameter in kubectl command.