# Difference between kubectl port-forwarding and proxy

Tags: kubernetes

`kubectl proxy` and `kubectl port-forwarding` look similar and confusing to me, what are their main differences and use cases?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How `kubectl port-forward` works?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51469150/6309)"

> `kubectl port-forward` forwards connections to a local port to a port on a pod.
>
> Compared to `kubectl proxy`, `kubectl port-forward` is more generic as it can forward TCP traffic while `kubectl proxy` can only forward HTTP traffic.

As an example, see "[Kubernetes port forwarding simple like never before](https://medium.com/pixelpoint/kubernetes-port-forwarding-simple-like-never-before-20a8ab16370f)" from [Alex Barashkov](https://twitter.com/alex_barashkov):

> **Port forwarding mostly used for the purpose of getting access to internal cluster resources and debugging**.
>
> How does it work?
>
> Generally speaking, using port forwarding you could get on your ‘localhost’ any services launched in your cluster.
>   For example, if you have Redis installed in the cluster on 6379, by using a command like this:
>
> ```
> kubectl port-forward redis-master-765d459796-258hz 7000:6379
> ```
>
> you could forward Redis from the cluster to localhost:7000, access it locally and do whatever you want to do with it.

For a limited HTTP access, see kubectl proxy, and, as an example, "[On Securing the Kubernetes Dashboard](https://blog.heptio.com/on-securing-the-kubernetes-dashboard-16b09b1b7aca)" from [Joe Beda](https://twitter.com/jbeda):

> The easiest and most common way to access the cluster is through kubectl proxy. This creates a local web server that securely proxies data to the dashboard through the Kubernetes API server.

As shown in "[A Step-By-Step Guide To Install & Use Kubernetes Dashboard](https://medium.com/edureka/kubernetes-dashboard-d909b8b6579c)" from [Awanish](https://twitter.com/edurekaIN):

> ```
> kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
> ```
>
> Accessing Dashboard using the kubectl
>
> ```
> kubectl proxy
> ```
>
> It will proxy server between your machine and Kubernetes API server.
>
> Now, to view the dashboard in the browser, navigate to the following address in the browser of your Master VM:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
> ```

Comment: how would you do same for production not only for debugging?

Comment: @GiorgiBeria For production, you would use a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) instead of `kubectl port-forward`, as mentioned in "[`kubectl port-forward` can be dangerous used in prod environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59174147/6309)"