# kubectl port-forward can be dangerous used in prod environment?

Tags: kubernetes, production-environment, portforwarding

I would like to know if port-forward blocks other requests to the pod like redis, mongo, etc.

If I use kubectl port-foward command with mongo port for example, the mongo server will not receive the data ?

Comment: Can't understand what you are asking... Do you mean to ask if port-forward blocks other requests to the pod when you do it?

Comment: @night-gold exact! I can edit post to clarify the question

Comment: It would make no sense to do `port-forward` for prod environment.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment, `kubectl port-forward` does not block any exposed traffic to the target pod. So adding portforward won't affect others.

What `portforward` does is simply making a specific request to the API server. (see [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#create-connect-portforward-pod-v1-core))

Going further, I don't think `port-forward` makes pod more "dangerous" (vulnerable against security), however it is generally used for debugging to scope into the pod, not to expose a service in the pod. Use `Nodeport` service for production.
Plus, `port-forward` has default [timeout setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484312/kubectl-port-forwarding-timeout-issue) in kubelet.