# RabbitMQ on Kubernetes - Can't login to the management UI

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm trying to switch an existing app from docker-compose to Kubernetes (first time using it).
My app is deployed on AWS EKS using Fargate nodes. It runs well, but I would like to access the RabbitMQ management UI for debugging purposes.

The rabbit deployment/services files I am using are the following:

```yaml
# rabbit-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: rabbit
  name: rabbit
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: rabbit
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: rabbit
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: rabbitmq:3.9.13-management
          name: rabbit
          ports:
            - containerPort: 15672
            - containerPort: 5672
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {}
          env:
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
              value: "guest"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
              value: "guest"
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

and

```yaml
# rabbit-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: rabbit
  name: rabbit
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: "15672"
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
    - name: "5672"
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
    - name: "8080"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: rabbit
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I also followed the instructions to create a new user:

```sh
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods --selector=io.kompose.service=rabbit -o template --template="{{(index .items 0).metadata.name}}") -- rabbitmqctl add_user test test

kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods --selector=io.kompose.service=rabbit -o template --template="{{(index .items 0).metadata.name}}") -- rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator

kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods --selector=io.kompose.service=rabbit -o template --template="{{(index .items 0).metadata.name}}") -- rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

I can access the webUI on

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/rabbit:15672/proxy/
```

after activating the proxy with `kubectl proxy`, however, login with `test` and `test` still gives me a **Login failed** message.

Comment: Can you access it via `nodePort` or create a `loadbalancer` service to test? I recreated this config with `loadbalancer` and it works fine. To understand if the issue with commands/deployment. Also you can try [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) to pod.

Comment: Did you try the guest:guest default user? I also second the call to use `kubectl port-forward`.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know why it wasn't working with `kubectl proxy`, but using `kubectl port-forward deployment/rabbit 15672:15672` was the way to go. I had no knowledge of that command but this allowed me to login with the `guest:guest` credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer out of comments.

---

First what [`kubectl proxy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#proxy) is:

> Creates a proxy server or application-level gateway between localhost
> and the Kubernetes API server. It also allows serving static content
> over specified HTTP path. All incoming data enters through one port
> and gets forwarded to the remote Kubernetes API server port, except
> for the path matching the static content path.

Also `kubectl proxy` works with HTTP requests, it does not work with TCP traffic. (this is probably the reason why it did not work).

You can read more in a [good answer - kubectl proxy vs kubectl port-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360741/15537201)

---

Common options to access the service inside the cluster are:

- use [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) - for local development and testing purposes
- use `loadbalancer` or `nodeport` service type - more advanced options which can be used across clusters and production environments. Find more about [service types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).