# How to access a service from other machine in LAN?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, portforwarding, kubernetes-service

Hello Im learning kubernetes with the minikube. I can access a service via minikubeip:NodePort on the machine where the minikube is running and now I want to access the Service via LAN from other machine. I tried ingress but it didn't work for me.

Deployment file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aspnetapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: aspnetapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aspnetapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aspnetapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: aspnetapp-cn
          image: localhost:5000/aspnetapp
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
```

Service file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: aspnetapp-service
spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - name: http
      targetport: 80      
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    selector:
      app: aspnetapp
```

Ingress file:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aspnetapp-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host:
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /aspnetapp
          backend:
            serviceName: aspnetapp-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Hello, it's really good that you've managed to connect to your application on your host. To be able to help you further you'll need to tell which operating system are you using as well as the `--driver` used by your minikube.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for ur replay and my driver is docker and im using ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

To expose your application to LAN with Ubuntu with a `--docker` driver you can use:

- `$ kubectl port-forward ...`

> Disclaimer!
>
> 1. Your `$ kubectl port-forward` should be run on a **host** running minikube.
> 2. Command above will operate continuously (`&` can be used to run it in a background)

Example:

Let's assume that you have an Ubuntu machine with IP: `192.168.0.115`.

I've created an example using `nginx` image:

`Deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

As for the service exposing your `Deployment` you can **either**:

- Use following command:

  - `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=NodePort`
- Use definition below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

---

---

You can expose your `nginx` in two ways:

- Directly with `$ kubectl port-forward`.
- Directing the traffic to the `Ingress` controller.

---

#### Direct access

You can expose your `Service` directly without using `Ingress` by:

- `$ kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 deployment/nginx 10000:80`

Dissecting above command:

- `--address=0.0.0.0` - expose outside of localhost
- `deployment/nginx` - resource/resource_name
- `10000:80` - port on host machine/port on pod to send the traffic to

> Assigning local ports under 1024 will need root access!
>
> You will need to login to root and either copy `.kube/config` to `/root/` directory or specify where `kubectl` should look for config!

After running above command you should be able to run:

- `curl 192.168.1.115:10000`

Command `$ kubectl port-forward` will generate:

```sh
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:10000 -> 80 # AT THE START
Handling connection for 10000 # CURL FROM 192.168.0.2
```

---

#### Directing the traffic to the `Ingress` controller

> You need to run `$ minikube addons enable ingress` to have functionalities of `Ingress` resource

In your example you used `Ingress` resource. In this situation you should:

- Create `Ingress` resource (as you did).

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

- Forward the traffic to the `Ingress` controller!

`Ingress` controller after receiving the traffic will forward it further (to your `Service` and then to `Pod`)

To forward the traffic to your `Ingress` controller run this command:

- `kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 --namespace=kube-system deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80`

Dissecting above command once more:

- `--address=0.0.0.0` - expose outside of localhost
- `--namespace=kube-system` - namespace that the `Deployment` of `Ingress` controller resides in
- `deployment/ingress-nginx-controller` - resource/resource-name
- `80:80` - port on host machine/port on pod to send the traffic to

Command `$ kubectl port-forward` will generate:

```sh
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:80 -> 80 # AT THE START 
Handling connection for 80 # CURL FROM 192.168.0.2
```

---

I also encourage you to use different `--driver` like for example Virtualbox. You will be able to expose your application without `$ kubectl port-forward` (NAT).

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: How kubectl port-forward works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468491/how-kubectl-port-forward-works)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I used the portforward option without ingress as first and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The ingress option seems not working:
kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 --namespace=kube-system deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80

I get the following error:
error: unable to forward port because pod is not running. Current status=Pending

minikube version is v1.20.0
ingress controller version is v0.44.0

Example setup:
Trying to access web services deployed in a minikube cluster from another machine in the same LAN. In the host machine, the service is accessed like, 'http://express.api/users'. 'express.api' is resolved using an entry in hosts file to ingress IP address.

Comment: kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 --namespace=kube-system deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80 is pointing to a 'deployment'  it needs to point to the ingress-nginx-controller 'service'

Comment: Looks like 'ingress-nginx-controller' pod was in pending status after minikube upgrade to v1.20.0 (Inspecting output of 'kubectl get pods -n kube-system'). After reenabling the ingress addon once, the pod changed it's status to running (Not sure the exact reason). 
This was the reason for error:
error: unable to forward port because pod is not running. Current status=Pending

Below command is working after re-enabling ingress controller.
kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 --namespace=kube-system deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80

Comment: On a recent installation of minikube, I noticed that the namespace of ingress controller is changed to 'ingress-nginx'. In this instance the below command worked:
kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 --namespace=ingress-nginx deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80

Answer (score 0):

well if you are on doker desktop based kubernetes, this hacked worked for me
127.0.0.1:6443 works, but where as yourlapip:6443  from remote machine does not work..
quick easy work around is to manage it in windows host machine. by port forwarding

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=6443 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

then access k8s api from remote machine (connected to your network through) https://machinesnetworkip:4000