# How to route test traffic through kubernetes cluster (minikube)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster

I have a minikube cluster with two pods (with ubuntu containers). What I need to do is route test traffic from one port to another through this minikube cluster. This traffic should be sent through these two pods like in the picture. I am a beginner in this Kubernetes stuff so I really don't know how to do this and which way to go... Please, help me or give me some hints.

I am working on ubuntu server ver. **18.04.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwRfs.png)

Comment: Could you please include the driver you are using with your `minikube`? Is it a `docker` or a `virtualbox`? There are some differences when it comes to exposing traffic with different drivers. Also I'd reckon this documentation could be helpful to you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: I'am using kvm as a tool for create minikube vm. I want to route L2 traffic through my cluster. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I haven't tested it on `KVM` but I'd reckon that `kubectl port-forward` should work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with an answer provided by @Harsh Manvar and I would also like to expand a little bit on this topic.

There already is an answer with a similar setup. I encourage you to check it out:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How to access a service from other machine in LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350158/how-to-access-a-service-from-other-machine-in-lan/64422184#64422184)*

There are different [drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) that could be used to run your `minikube`. **They will have differences when it comes to dealing with inbound traffic.** I missed the part that was telling about the driver used in the setup (comment). If it's the `Docker` shown in the tags, you could follow below example.

---

## Example

Steps:

- Spawn `nginx-one` and `nginx-two` `Deployments` to imitate `Pods` from the image
- Create a service that will be used to send traffic from `nginx-one` to `nginx-two`
- Create a service that will allow you to connect to `nginx-one` from LAN
- Test the setup

#### Spawn `nginx-one` and `nginx-two` `Deployments` to imitate `Pods` from the image

You can use following definitions to spawn two `Deployments` where each one will have a single `Pod`:

- `nginx-one.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-one
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-one
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-one
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

- `nginx-two.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-two
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-two
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-two
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

#### Create a service that will be used to send traffic from `nginx-one` to `nginx-two`

You will need to use a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to send the traffic from `nginx-one` to `nginx-two`. Example of such `Service` could be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-two-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP # could be changed to NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-two # IMPORTANT
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

After applying this definition you will be able to send the traffic to `nginx-two` by using the service name (`nginx-two-service`)

> A side note!
>
> You can use the IP of the `Pod` without the `Service` but this is not a recommended way.

#### Create a service that will allow you to connect to `nginx-one` from LAN

Assuming that you want to expose your `minikube` instance to LAN with `Docker` driver you will need to create a service and expose it. Example of such setup could be the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-one-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP # could be changed to NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-one # IMPORTANT
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

You will also need to run:

- `$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/nginx-one-service 8000:80`

Above command (ran on your `minikube` host!) will expose your `nginx-one-service` to be available on LAN. It will map port 8000 on the machine that ran this command to the port 80 of this service. You can check it by executing from another machine at LAN:

- `curl IP_ADDRESS_OF_MINIKUBE_HOST:8000`

> A side note!
>
> You will need root access to have your inbound traffic enter on ports lesser than 1024.

#### Test the setup

You will need to check if there is a communication between the objects as shown in below "connection diagram".

`PC` -> `nginx-one` -> `nginx-two` -> `example.com`

The testing methodology could be following:

`PC` -> `nginx-one`:

- Run on a machine in your LAN:

  - `curl MINIKUBE_IP_ADDRESS:8000`

`nginx-one` -> `nginx-two`:

- Exec into your `nginx-one` `Pod` and run command:

  - `$ kubectl exec -it NGINX_POD_ONE_NAME -- /bin/bash`
  - `$ curl nginx-two-service`

`nginx-two` -> `example.com`:

- Exec into your `nginx-two` `Pod` and run command:

  - `$ kubectl exec -it NGINX_POD_TWO_NAME -- /bin/bash`
  - `$ curl example.com`

If you completed above steps you can swap `nginx` `Pods` for your own software.

---

Additional notes and resources:

I encourage you to check `kubeadm` as it's the tool to create your own Kubernetes clusters:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Create cluster kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)*

As you said:

> I am a beginner in this Kubernetes stuff so I really don't know how to do this and which way to go... Please, help me or give me some hints.

You could check following links for more resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/)*
- *[Kubernetes: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your tutorial! It helped a lot.
However this part does not work for me: PC -> nginx-one. I have curl (7) ... port 8000: connection refused :( and I really dont know what to do with this. This command kubectl forward port i am executing directly on server, while minikube is running, yes?
the rest : nginx-one-> nginx-two -> example.com works.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options you can follow:

As you have two PODs you can expose one via service,

1. so service-1 is exposed and sending traffic to POD-1
2. POD-1 will send a request to service-2 of Kubernetes
3. This way traffic will get forwarded to POD-2 and from there it will Go out of cluster

There is also a container to container communication possibility if you can run both applications in a single POD.

POD-1 to POD-2 communication you can use the service option or POD URI.

Comment: Hi! thank you for a hint! "This way traffic will get forwarded to POD-2 and from there it will Go out of cluster" from there means from pod 2 or service 2?

Comment: from POD-2 ideally, as an application running inside pOD-2 will forward traffic out....if you are using a module request with node js or python client will directly forward traffic from pod.