# How to route traffic from pysical server's port to minikube cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I want to sent traffic from one port through kubernetes cluster (using minikube) to another physical port. I don't know how to route traffic from physical port to cluster and from cluster to the second physical port. I'm exposing cluster via ingress (and I tested service solution also), i have one service to send external tarffic to pod and another to sent traffic from first pod to second pod. But I really don't know how to send this traffic from port to cluster and how to sent from cluster to receiving port...

My cluster is described in there: [How to route test traffic through kubernetes cluster (minikube)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560792/how-to-route-test-traffic-through-kubernetes-cluster-minikube?noredirect=1#comment116209115_65560792)

Comment: Hello, I have some difficulty to exactly tell what are you trying to accomplish. Could you please rephrase your question? Do you mean that you cannot access your Kubernetes cluster from external sources (like other device in the network)?

Comment: Hi again Dawid! I just simply don't know how to sent this test traffic from physical port to cluster, to the service one (and from cluster to receiving port). I also don't have idea how to sent it through ubuntu container in pod...

Comment: Please edit your question and include any part that is not clear to you. I will explain it to you in greater detail. Also, from the point of physical port, are you referring to the actual port in your machine? Also could you tell more about the traffic that you are sending? Could you tell more about your use case?

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to route traffic from port to ingress (or service), and then from service or pod to another receiving port. Physical port - I mean port on my bare-metal server (I'm not working on my local machine, i'm doing it on server in lab, and thats why I want to sent traffic from physical port; to this physical port I have traffic generator connected). I'am sending L2 traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- Traffic needs to enter through a **physical** `enp0s6` port on `Ubuntu` Server and be sent to `Pod`
- `Pod` is configured with some software capable of routing traffic.
- `Pod` from the image is routing traffic received to a **physical** `enp0s5` port on the same `Ubuntu` Server machine (or further down the line).

[image: Diagram]

This answer does not acknowledge:

- Software used to route the traffic from `Pod` to a physical port `enp0s5`.

> A side note!
>
> Please consider entering each link that I included in the answer as there are a lot of useful information.

---

[Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) is a tool that spawn your single node Kubernetes cluster for development purposes on your machine (PC, Laptop, Server, etc.).

It uses different drivers to run Kubernetes (it can be deployed as `bare-metal`, in `docker`, in `virtualbox`, in `kvm`, etc.). This allows for isolation from host (`Ubuntu` Server). It also means that there are differences when it comes to the networking part of this setup.

By the setup of `minikube` with `kvm2` driver you will need to make some additional changes to your setup to be able to route traffic from `192.168.0.150` to your [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) (set of `Pods`).

Let' assume that the `Deployment` manifest is following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Also let's assume that the `Service` manifest is following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  type: NodePort 
  selector:
    app: nginx # <-- this needs to match with Deployment matchLabels
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

`Service` of type `NodePort` from above example will expose your `Deployment` on a `minikube` instance (IP) on port `30000`.

In this particular example `Service` ([An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)) will expose the `Pod` within `minikube` instance and your host but **not** for external access (like other machine in the `192.168.0.0/24` network).

Options to allow external traffic are either:

- **Run on your host** (`Ubuntu` Server):

  - `$ kubectl port-forward --address 192.168.0.150 service/nginx-deployment 8000:80`

`kubectl` will allow connections on your `Ubuntu` Server on port `8000` to be forwarded directly to the `nginx-deployment` service and inherently to your `Pod`.

> Side notes!
>
> - You can also use `kubectl port-forward` on your PC/Laptop and by that you can direct traffic from the PC/Laptop port to your `Pod`.
> - `--address 192.168.0.150` is set to target specifically `enp0s6`.

- **Use OS built-in port forwarding**.

You can read more about it by following this answer:

- *[Serverfault: Setup bridge for existing virtual birdge that minikube is running on](https://serverfault.com/a/969106/545585)*

---

Above explanation should help you to direct the traffic to your `Pod` directly from `enp0s6`. Sending traffic from `Pod` to your `enp0s5` interface is pretty straightforward. You can run (**from your `Pod`**):

- `curl 10.0.0.150` (`enp0s5`)
- `curl 10.0.0.X` (device in `enp0s5` network)

---

#### Alternative

As an alternative you can try to provision your own Kubernetes cluster without using `minikube`. This will inherently eliminate the isolation layer and allow you for a more direct access. There are a lot of options like for example:

- [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)
- [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
- [MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/)

---

I encourage you to check the additional resources as Kubernetes is a complex solution and there is a lot to discover:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Home](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/)*