# How to run echo server inside Kubernetes (with docker container) to communicate with it form other machines in local environment?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

What I want to achieve is to run the simplest echo server using `python` and `tornado`, code here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 8080
    print ("Starting up echo server at port %d" % port)
    enable_pretty_logging()
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(int(port))
    
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I want to run it inside docker that is running inside kubernetes's Pod.
I already achieved it but only partly. I'm running kubernetes cluster on physical machine, which is in my local network. To run cluster I used `minikube`.
Here are my configuration files, which I use to run kubernetes `Deployment` and `Service`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testApp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testApp-container
        image: testApp-docker:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        command: ["python3"]
        args: ["-u", "echo_tornado.py"]

        ports:
        - containerPort: 5020
      restartPolicy: Always
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testApp-svc
  labels:
    app: testApp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5020
    targetPort: 5020
    nodePort: 5020
  selector:
    app: testApp
```

What is problem exactly ? I can sent request to my echo server by `curl $NODE_IP:$NODE_PORT` and I'm getting a response, but I also want to be able do `curl localhost:$NODE_PORT` and also (what is crucial for me) I must be able to do `curl $MY_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP:$NODE_PORT` from other machine inside same local network.

Is it possible to achieve it ? Should I use some kind of forwarding my local IP and port to node's ip ?
Maybe I shouldn't use `ServiceType : NodePort` and I should use `LoadBalancer` ?
Maybe `minikube` is a problem and I should use different tool ?

Comment: Kubernetes is intrinsically a remote clustered environment; the NodePort service will almost never be `localhost` or the local system.  You'd typically configure a load balancer (either manually or with a LoadBalancer service) with a DNS name and have clients connect to that.

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand why I couldn't use NodePort in that case. I changed my ServiceType to LoadBalancer, now I can communicate with my echo server via my loadBalancer's external IP, but still I can use this IP only from my machine (this with minikube cluster), but I wish to be able to talk with this echo server from others machines in same local network. What else should I do ?

Comment: @Dariusz.O It's possible but the solution will depend on the `--driver` and OS you use. `Minikube` by itself provides an "isolation layer" (what I mean by that is exposing it on LAN). Please add the OS and `--driver` you use to your question. You can try to run on the host that is having `minikube` instance: `kubectl port-forward svc/testApp-svc 5020:5020 --address 0.0.0.0`. You can also look on other solutions like `kubeadm`, `kubespray`, `microk8s`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) is a tool that spawn your single node Kubernetes cluster for development purposes on your machine (PC, Laptop, Server, etc.).

It uses different `--drivers` to run Kubernetes (it can be deployed as `bare-metal`, in `docker`, in `virtualbox`, in `kvm`, etc.). This allows for isolation from host and other devices. **It also means that there are differences when it comes to the networking part of this setup.**

There is a lot to cover when it comes to the networking part of Kubernetes. I encourage you to check the official docs:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

---

As the `driver` used and the `OS` is unknown it could be hard to pinpoint the exact solution. **Some** of the pointers that could help you:

- When you are using Linux distribution you can opt to use driver `--none`. It will use `Docker` but everything (containers like `kubeapi-server`, `etcd`, etc.) will be provisioned directly on your host. By that you could run: `$ curl $MY_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP:$NODE_PORT`). With `--driver=docker` everything I mentioned will be put in a `Docker` container.

> A side note!
>
> `--driver=none` have some limitations/issues (for example decreased security). You can read more about it by following this documentation:
>
> - *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers: None](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/)*

- As a workaround/**temporary solution** you can use previously mentioned (run on your host):

  - `$ kubectl port-forward svc/testApp-svc 5020:5020 --address 0.0.0.0` - this command will forward requests coming to your machine on port `5020` directly to the `Service: testApp-svc` on port `5020`.
- With other driver like for example `Virtualbox` you will need to reach the documentation of it for ability to expose your `minikube` instance on the LAN.

---

Seeing this part of the question:

> (what is crucial for me) I must be able to do curl $MY_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP:$NODE_PORT from other machine inside same local network.

It could beneficiary to add that there are other solution outside of `minikube` that could provision your Kubernetes cluster. There are some differences between them and you would need to chose the one that suits your requirements the most. **Some** of them are:

- *[Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)*
- *[Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)*
- *[MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/)*
- *[K3S](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/)*
- *[Kubernetes: The hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)*

> A side note!
>
> For assigning the `IP addresses` for a `LoadBalancer` type of `Service` you could look on [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) (when using above options).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How to route traffic from physical servers port to minikube cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65872990/how-to-route-traffic-from-pysical-servers-port-to-minikube-cluster)*
- *[Kubernetes: Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/)*