# How to access a pod on an external IP

Tags: linux, nginx, kubernetes

I have ran a pod on the control plane called kube-nginx, and forward port. And I am a freshman in kubernetes.

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:03:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

[root@k8smaster ~]# cat /opt/pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubectl get pod
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-nginx   1/1     Running   0          38m
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubectl port-forward pod/kube-nginx 10086:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:10086 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:10086 -> 80
```

I can access the pod on localhost, But I cannot access the pod on the extenal IP.

```
[root@k8smaster opt]# ip a | awk '/^2: ens33/,/^3: docker/{print $2}' | sed -n '3P'
192.168.80.201/24
[root@k8smaster opt]# nc -vz localhost 10086
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:10086.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
```

On the external IP host I can ping the k8smaster, but cannot access to the pod in it.

```
[root@k8snode01 opt]# ping -c 3 192.168.80.201
PING 192.168.80.201 (192.168.80.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.80.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.367 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.80.201: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.215 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.80.201: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.248 ms

--- 192.168.80.201 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.215/0.276/0.367/0.068 ms

[root@k8snode01 opt]# ip a | awk '/^2: ens33/,/^3: docker/{print $2}' | sed -n '3p'
192.168.80.202/24
[root@k8snode01 opt]# nc -nvz 192.168.80.201 10086
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
```

and the routing table show as follow

```
[root@k8snode01 opt]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.80.2    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.16.128  192.168.80.201  255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 ens33
192.168.80.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
```

the firewall settings

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# iptables-save | egrep -w -- INPUT
:INPUT ACCEPT [78784:15851659]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [61299:11943644]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:cali-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "cali:Cz_u1IQiXIMmKD4c" -j cali-INPUT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A cali-INPUT -p udp -m comment --comment "cali:w7ud0UgQSEi_zKuQ" -m comment --comment "Allow VXLAN packets from whitelisted hosts" -m multiport --dports 4789 -m set --match-set cali40all-vxlan-net src -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ACCEPT
-A cali-INPUT -p udp -m comment --comment "cali:4cgmbdWsLmozYhJh" -m comment --comment "Drop VXLAN packets from non-whitelisted hosts" -m multiport --dports 4789 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DROP
-A cali-INPUT -i cali+ -m comment --comment "cali:t45BUBhpu3Wsmi1_" -g cali-wl-to-host
-A cali-INPUT -m comment --comment "cali:NOmsycyknYZaGOFf" -m mark --mark 0x10000/0x10000 -j ACCEPT
-A cali-INPUT -m comment --comment "cali:Or0B7eoenKO2p8Bf" -j MARK --set-xmark 0x0/0xf0000
-A cali-INPUT -m comment --comment "cali:AmIfvPGG2lYUK6mj" -j cali-from-host-endpoint
-A cali-INPUT -m comment --comment "cali:79fWWn1SpufdO7SE" -m comment --comment "Host endpoint policy accepted packet." -m mark --mark 0x10000/0x10000 -j ACCEPT

[root@k8smaster ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens33
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Comment: @ Raman Sailopal the doc use kind Deployment to run pods, but I wanna use kind Pod to run pods. Could kind Pod expose port to a external IP ?

Comment: Hello, could you please tell more about how you've created your Kubernetes cluster? Also could you please tell what exactly are you trying to do with `$ kubectl port-forward`? I'd reckon you should use a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) instead of `port-forward` to expose your `kube-nginx` `Pod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To listen on port 10086 on all addresses, forwarding to 80 in the pod

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/kube-nginx 10086:80
```

Comment: I haven't see that output`Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:10086 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:10086 -> 80` LOL

Comment: Works great using --address 0.0.0.0 an easy way to expose de pod, nothing secure but works!

Answer (score 2):

Having in mind the following statement:

> And I am a freshman in kubernetes.

I think there are some topics that should be addressed:

- General thoughts on the question
- `$ kubectl port-forward ...`
- Working example

---

#### General thoughts on the question

Kubernetes as a platform has a specific objects to accomplish certain things/tasks. You've already created a `Pod` named `kube-nginx` which spawned on of the `Nodes`.

To expose `Pods` (like your `kube-nginx`) for internal/external sources you will need to use a `Service`. You can read more about it by following official documentation:

> #### Service
>
> An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.
> With Kubernetes you don't need to modify your application to use an unfamiliar service discovery mechanism. Kubernetes gives Pods their own IP addresses and a single DNS name for a set of Pods, and can load-balance across them.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

Your `Pod` definition is correct and it will spawn a single `Pod` with `nginx` image but Kubernetes won't be able to expose it to external sources (apart from `$ kubectl port-forward` which I will address later) due to lack of certain field in your manifest.

The minimal example that should be exposable with `Services`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

I do also think that you should be using other Kubernetes objects like for example `Deployment`:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)*

Also you haven't added anything to your manifest to force the `Pod` to be scheduled on the `k8smaster`. It could be scheduled on `k8snode01`. You can check on which `Node` your `Pod` is running by:

- `$ kubectl get pods/kube-nginx -o wide`

```sh
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP         --> NODE <--        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-nginx   1/1     Running   0          84m   10.32.2.7  --> raven-6k6m  <--  <none>           <none>
```

See the `Node` column.

---

#### `$ kubectl port-forward ...`

Coming onto the topic of `kubectl port-forward pod/kube-nginx 10086:80` command. This is a guess but I think the interpretation is that it will permanently expose the `kube-nginx` `Pod` on port: `10086` on a host that ran this command. Yes, it will expose your `Pod` but in this setup only on localhost and it will run as long as the command is running. **To expose your workload you should be using earlier mentioned `Services`.** If you want to expose your `Pod` with `$ kubectl port-forward` you should use the command as user @Phillipe pointed:

- `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/kube-nginx 10086:80`

The `--address 0.0.0.0` will allow incoming connections from your `LAN` (assuming no firewall dropping the requests).

Citing another answer from Stackoverflow.com:

> `kubectl port-forward` makes a specific [Kubernetes API request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#-strong-proxy-operations-pod-v1-core-strong-).  That means the system running it needs access to the API server, and any traffic will get tunneled over a single HTTP connection.
>
> Having this is really useful for debugging (if one specific pod is acting up you can connect to it directly; in a microservice environment you can talk to a back-end service you wouldn't otherwise expose) but it's not an alternative to setting up service objects.  When I've worked with `kubectl port-forward` it's been visibly slower than connecting to a pod via a service, and I've found seen the command just stop after a couple of minutes.  Again these aren't big problems for debugging, but they're not what I'd want for a production system.
>
> -- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: How kubectl port-forward works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476393/12257134)*

---

#### Working example

Assuming that your cluster is configured correctly as there are no steps in the question about the cluster provisioning process, you could use following example to expose your `kube-nginx` `Pod` to the external sources.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-nginx
  labels: 
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx # <-- this needs to match .metadata.labels field in Pod
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80 # <-- port inside of the cluster 
      targetPort: 80 # <-- port that app is listening on
      nodePort: 30080 # <-- from 30000 to 32767 on the node (can be changed)
```

By this example you will spawn a `Pod` with `nginx` image and allow the connections on port: `30080` on each `Node` to reach the `Pod`(i.e. `$ curl 192.168.0.114:30080)`.

`Service` of type `LoadBalancer` is also possible with it's `External IP` allocation but due to the lack of information on the Kubernetes setup, it could be hard to point to the right solution (on-premises=`metallb`, otherwise consult the provider documentation).

---

I also encourage you to check the following documentation to get more reference/best practices etc.:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/)*

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to attach a service type Loadbalances like below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-nginx
  namespace: <your namespace>
  labels:
    app: kube-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "your certificate"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600'
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: kube-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: proxy
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: http
```