# How to forward a k8 pod's port via jumphost

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, portforwarding

I can ssh into a jumphost from where I can accesss k8 cluster.
there is a particular pod which has a UI exposed on port 4040, how can I view that on my local browser ?

What I have figured out so far, by executing the below command

```
kubectl port-forward podName 4040:4040
```

I can now access the UI (by text based browser) on jumphost

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: how do I access the UI on my local laptop ?

Comment: k8 cluster can only be accessed via jumpbox

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727416/3098330

Comment: I cannot run `kubectl port-forward` from my laptop!

cluster is not accessible from my laptop.

If I run `kubectl port-forward` from jumphost, then it's half the job done, right ?

sorry If I am missing something trivial

Comment: Can you combine `ssh [user@jumphost] -L "4040:localhost:4000" "kubectl port-forward ..."` to port-forward over `ssh` (4040-->4040) and have `kubectl` port-forward the jumphost's 4040 to the cluster's 4040?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to be done in two steps

1st run `kubectl port-forward podName 4040:4040` from jumpbox

2nd run `ssh -L 4040:localhost:4040 -i some_key.pem user@jumpbox-server` from the local machine

access `http://localhost:4040`  using browser

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is an accepted answer, my situation is little different. After connecting to the jumphost with ssh, I have tried the above port forwarding command and it was working fine but for some reason I can't access these exposed port using step 2 from my local machine.

Here is what I did. Added --address 0.0.0.0 to the existing port forward command.

1. Inside the Jumphost

> kubectl port-forward podname --address 0.0.0.0 7000:8080 -n namespace

2. From my local machine, created a tunnel because I can't access our jumphost with user@jumphostname. So I have to use the resource id to specify the jumphost id, so I followed this command.

> az network bastion tunnel --name hubname --resource-group
> resourcegroupname --subscription subscriptionid --target-resource-id
> vmresourceid --resource-port 7000 --port 8000

From local machine you can start using via postman or browser with `http://localhost:8000`

It might be useful to someone. :)