# How kubernetes port-forward choose pod when forward to a deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Let say there's a deployment named my-deployment which is consisted of 3 pods, now we use port-forward forward a local port to this deployment :

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/my-deployment 8888 9999
```

My question is : when I visit localhost:8888 serveral times then which pod would be forwarded to ? Always forward to a fixed pod(like first pod) ? Or forward it by random ? Or use round-roubin strategy ?

Comment: Yes a fixed pod selected at the time the forwarding is established. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51468491/1032785

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`when I visit localhost:8888 serveral times then which pod would be forwarded to ?`

Will forward to the first pod sorted by name.

`Always forward to a fixed pod(like first pod) ?`

Fixed.

`Or forward it by random ? Or use round-roubin strategy ?`

Fixed to the first pod sorted by name.

Presumed you have performed a port-forward command and curl successfully. Now if you scale the deployment to 0; then scale up; if you curl again now you will get an error. This is because the pod that the port forwarded to has been terminated during the scale to 0.

Comment: Thx a lot, is there any references that I can dive deep into it ?  I've tried search this question but get nothing.

Comment: You can start digging [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/portforward/portforward.go) and all the way to the server side, if you like.

Comment: That's very helpful, I'll check this out.