# Kubernetes service proxy

Tags: kubernetes, networking

Kuberenetes newbie here, we have a jms server outside the cluster thats only accessible through our cluster, how can I create a port forward proxy on the cluster so I can connect to it via my local pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy is an application layer function or feature, whereas port forwarding is really just a manual entry in one of the NAPT tables. A proxy understands the application protocol and can be used as a single entry point for multiple exposed servers.

The NGINX Ingress Controller for Kubernetes (as a proxy) is compatible with the NGINX web server. If you want to [access workloads](https://docs.giantswarm.io/getting-started/exposing-workloads/) that are already running on your cluster from outside of it. Creating an Ingress resource is the standard procedure. In your workload cluster, add an ingress controller. For installation instructions, see this [page](https://docs.giantswarm.io/getting-started/ingress-controller/).

**Kubernetes port forwarding:**

This is especially useful when you want to directly communicate with a specific port on a Pod from your local machine, according to the official kubernetes [Connect with Port Forwarding](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-port-forward/#:%7E:text=Compared%20to%20kubectl%20proxy%2C%20kubectl,be%20useful%20for%20database%20debugging) documentation. Additionally, you don't have to manually expose services to accomplish this. Kubectl port-forward, on the other hand, moves connections from a local port to a pod port. Kubectl port-forward is more general than `kubectl proxy` because it can forward TCP traffic while kubectl proxy can only forward HTTP traffic. Although Kubectl simplifies port forwarding, it should only be utilized for debugging.

You can learn more about how to [use port-forward to access applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) in a cluster and another similar info [link](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubectl-port-forward) & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468491) aids in better comprehension.

Finally, for more information, see [Port-Forwarding and Proxy Server and Client Deployment](https://docs.armor.com/display/KBSS/Port-Forwarding+and+Proxy+Server+and+Client+Deployment.mobile.phone).