# Pod produces 502 Gateway nginx error when trying to navigate to the site

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, deployment, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to create a pod in kubernetes using the script below. The pod starts up normally but when I try to navigate to the website I see a screen saying "502 Bad Gateway" and below that it says "nginx".

I have tryied everything I can think of but nothing seems to work so I seek some help!

Kind regards Mitar

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: my-name
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-name
---
# LetsEncrypt certificate
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my-name
  labels:
    env: "Test"
spec:
  secretName: my-name
  dnsNames:
    - "my-name"
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-name
  namespace: my-name
  labels:
    app: my-name
    env: "Test"
    monitoring: someMonitoringTech
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-name
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
    - name: internal
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5105
    - name: metrics
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 5001
---
# pod
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-name
  namespace: my-name
  labels:
    app: my-name
    env: "Test"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-name
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-name
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-name
          image: "myregistry/mypathToImage:1"
          env:
            - name: SOME_ENVIRONEMENT
              value: "Test"
            - name: SOMEURLS
              value: "http://*:5000;http://*:5105"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "0.1"
              memory: "150Mi"
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-name
  namespace: my-name
  labels:
    app: my-name
    env: "Test"
    component: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "site.myname.com"
      secretName: my-name
  rules:
    - host: "site.myname.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-name
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

I tried looking at the dockerfile seeing the ports it mentioned and checked if those ports matched up with my ports.

I tried seeing if the pod has the apropriate labels.

I tried changing the ports, namesm, etc.

I double checked with a working YAML file.

I am expecting that the website is accessible and runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just missing the `tragetPort` in service manifest?

```yaml
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-name
  namespace: my-name
  labels:
    app: my-name
    env: "Test"
    monitoring: someMonitoringTech
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-name
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      # or targetPort: web
    - name: internal
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5105
    - name: metrics
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 5001
```

If this does not help, try running a `portForward` to that service and pod locally to see if each of one is running correctly

Comment: So I tried adding a target port and it didn't change the outcome. Also how do I do "portForward" I looked it up on azure devOps and there it showed the service, ingress and pod running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51469150/15111105

Comment: I found my problem actually I did not expose the right port thanks for your help.